# Java Regexp for matching all the content between "<" and ">" in a paragraph

Tags: java, regex

I have the following paragraph:

```
<p class="cms-body-text" style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px  0px 10px; line-height: 25.6px; background-color: #ffffff;">This is a test. This is another test. This is a third test<a href="javascript:%20window.print();">Print / Save as PDF</a></p><h3 class="cms-h3">TEST</h3>
```

I need a Java regexp that matches all the content between `<` and `>` only. This is what I've tried:

```
<[aA-zZ]+\s[aA-zZ]+="(.+)\>
```

This is not working because it is matching the text which is not surrounded by the `<` and `>`characters as well.

Any help?

Comment: I guess you meant `[a-zA-Z]`, not `[aA-zZ]`. To match as few as possible, use [lazy quantifiers](https://regex101.com/r/zN7kE5/1). And if you need a safer tool when parsing HTML, use the dedicated libraries.

Comment: Do you really _need_ a regex? When dealing with XML/html tags I'd encourage you to use a proper API like jsoup for example.